# puppet declarative language "defining Metaparameter subscribe rule to define::name"

Tags: puppet

I have the below puppet class and I have trouble in defining Metaparameter ( subscribe ) rule in one of the code snippet that I have pointed out using arrows.

[image]

**I don't know how to subscribe nexus::artifact to exec**

**artifact.pp**

```
define nexus::artifact (
  $gav,
  $repository,
  $output,
  $packaging  = 'jar',
  $classifier = undef,
  $ensure     = update,
  $timeout    = undef,
  $owner      = undef,
  $group      = undef,
  $mode       = undef
) {
    include nexus
}
```

**init.pp**

```
class nexus (
  $url,
  $username = undef,
  $password = undef,
  $netrc = undef,
) {
}
```

Comment: Please convert that screenshot into text and explain what kind of resource `nexus::artifact` is.

Comment: Matt, question updated...

Comment: subscribe=> Nexus::Artifact['nexus-artifact'] work ???

Comment: You are declaring the `nexus` class in two places and then putting an ignored `include` inside a custom define where all the parameters are being ignored. I don't believe your code is going to do what you want it to.

Comment: Matt, one is class definition, and the one present in nexusdeploy is, initialization...see there is no class name followed by class.... its just class {'classname':}....btw, nexusdeploy is doing what I wanat.... just the subscribe code I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my own answer that worked after going through puppet tutorials,
We can refer definition resources using the below code

> subscribe=>Nexus::Artifact['artifact-name']

For example, in my case,

```
exec {
    'exec':
    subscribe=>Nexus::Artifact['artifact-name'],
  }
```